# Xpath to an anchor returning error: unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, nunit

I am new to automated testing. I am using C#, Selenium and Chrome 99 with the correct driver.  I am trying to get to an anchor tag on the page.

Here is my code that is not working,

```
driver.Url = "abc.com"; //cant display the real one
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='ubEntryQueue.aspx']")).Click();
```

The error I am getting:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/a[@href='ubEntryQueue.aspx']"}
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.74)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<.ctor>b__11_0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at CLQTesting.WQ.ValidateWQDisplays() in C:\QA\CLQTesting\WQ.cs:line 30
```

This was my last attempt

Here is what I am trying to get to
[image]

Comment: What happens if you add a breakpoint to the `driver.FindElement` call and run in debug mode? Specifically, is the link visible on the browser screen? It looks like there are parent elements of the link that are set not to display - this will hide all child elements so Selenium would be unable to find them.

Comment: that makes sense.  How can I get around this?  Displayed=false when I debug it.  I thought that might be the issue but not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent `div` (and possibly other parent elements as well) has a style attribute of `display:none` which prevents any child elements from displaying.

There are several ways to get around this problem.

1. Program the actions needed to make the target element display. This may or may not be feasible depending on the way the site works - the HTML snippet shown in the question suggests that a lot of JavaScript is used to handle changing visibility and expanding elements.
2. Use the WebDriver `JavaScriptExecutor` class `ExecuteScript` method to edit the style directly. To do this, you will need to get a reference to a parent of the element with `display:none`, then use `ExecuteScript` to traverse the DOM and delete the `display:none` style tag. From there you can proceed as normal.
3. Use `JavaScriptExecutor` to click the link directly. This is probably the simplest method.

You can find a decent guide to using `JavaScriptExecutor` [here](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-use-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium-webdriver/). (I found the link with a quick Google search. No affiliation)

Comment: This is working perfect.  Thanks